# jQuery delete table column

Tags: jquery

I have a table and cannot change markup:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                blablabla
            </th>
            <th>
                blablabla
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                efgd
            </td>
            <td>
                efghdh
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my function, which should delete a column. It is called on cell click:

```
function (menuItem, menu) {
    var colnum = $(this).prevAll("td").length;

    $(this).closest('table').find('thead tr th:eq('+colnum+')').remove();
    $(this).closest("table").find('tbody tr td:eq('+colnum+')').remove();    
    return;
}
```

But it deletes something else, not the column I wanted to delete. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I can't see your intention here, please give more specific. You wanna delete all of it or just specific columns?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A column is pretty much just cells, so you'll need to manually loop through all the rows and remove the cell by the index.

This should give you a good starting point for removing the 3rd column:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).children("td:eq(2)").remove();
});
```

Comment: This does not quite work. `filter()` is applied to the `tr` elements, not the `td` elements, so this doesn't remove anything. Instead you need to either do `$(this).children().filter()` or better `$(this).find()`.

Answer (score 10):

This uses `.delegate()` for the handler, and a more native approach using `cellIndex` to get the cell index that was clicked, and `cells` to pull the cell from each row.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zZDKg/1/

```
$('table').delegate('td,th', 'click', function() {
    var index = this.cellIndex;
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
        this.removeChild(this.cells[ index ]);
    });
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged. At the time of the answer delegate was the right thing to use

Answer (score 10):

This works fine for me:

```
$(".tableClassName tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td:eq(3)").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have the static html (consider table with 10 columns),

then remove the first column along with header using below:

```
 $('#table th:nth-child(1),#table td:nth-child(1)').remove();
```

now the new table will have 9 columns , now you can remove any column using the number:

```
 $('#table th:nth-child(7),#table td:nth-child(7)').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first column from each row.

```
$('.mytable').find("tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
    $(this).remove()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By Applying some class on targeted column we can remove it.
For example

```
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><button class="btnRemoveMember">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

From above example table we can remove 3rd column of table as follow.

```
$(.btnRemoveMember).closest('td').remove();
```