# Delete column at jquery DataTable with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html-table, datatables

I use the table plug-in for jquery [Datatable](http://datatables.net/index)  at my rails app, and i look for a way to delete the whole column if some actions occurs e.g. if a button was clicked.

The table:

```
<table id="words" class="display" data-source="<%= url_for controller:"words", action: "index", :format=>:json %>" >
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= l(:name) %></th>
       .
       .
       .
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have your tried? an nth-child selector applied to the TDs would do the trick.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544177/jquery-delete-table-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544177/jquery-delete-table-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, **nth-child selector** works(thx @TrueBlueAussie) for my the following way:

```
$('#words thead').find("tr th:nth-child(5)").each(function(){$(this).remove()});
$('#words tbody').find("tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function(){$(this).remove()});
```

It removes the 5'th column from my table.