# Delete column contents in html table with loop

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have an html table with rows filled from loop and I want to delete the last two columns from all those rows inside click event on print button :

**JS :**

```
$("#print").on('click', function(){  
     //I want to remove columns HERE
})
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery delete table column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544177/jquery-delete-table-column)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to delete two columns..The datas coming from the loop.I want to delete the column values

Comment: node.removeChild(node),   may be this will you can use in loop to remove entire column, clarify your question... do you want to remove column or just want to remove data in those column?
node.textContent = '',,,,,,,, will remove data of the cell

Comment: i want to delete last two columns

Comment: Still not clear. Removing the row from the table won't delete the source data, if that loaded from some backend like PHP/MySQL. Are you trying to just delete a table row from the DOM, or the data that populates it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that what you really looking for (delete columns or columns content) but you can try the followings suggestions.

**Delete the last two columnns :**

You can just call the following code that remove last child several times as much as the number of columns you want to remove :

```
$("table").find("th:last-child, td:last-child").remove();
```

---

```js
$("#print").on('click', function(){  
    var remove_cols_number =2;
    
    for(var i=0;i<remove_cols_number;i++){
     $("table").find("th:last-child, td:last-child").remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th> 
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td> 
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Gates</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button id='print' type="button">Print</button>
```

**Delete the last two columns content :**

You can get the columns length and remove one since the `eq()` use a zero based index, then use `empty()` to remove content of last one and the column before it last one -1 :

```
var columns_length = $("table th").length-1;

$("table tr").find("td:eq("+columns_length+"), td:eq("+(columns_length-1)+")").empty();
```

---

```js
$("#print").on('click', function(){  
    var columns_length = $("table th").length-1;

    $("table tr").find("td:eq("+columns_length+"), td:eq("+(columns_length-1)+")").empty();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th> 
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td> 
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Gates</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button id='print' type="button">Print</button>
```