# Delete Column with JavaScript shorter way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there can someone please help me with this, I have this code:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button[id=delete_column]', function () {

    if (col_number > 1) {
      $('#column' + col_number).remove();
      $('#column' + col_number).remove();
      $('#column' + col_number).remove();
      $('#column' + col_number).remove();
      --col_number;
        }
     });
```

I need to delete the entire column and this ways it works how can I simplify this code not to repeat so many times, I tried something like this:

```
  $(document).on('click', 'button[id=delete_column]', function () {
      for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    if (col_number > 1) {
      $('#column' + col_number[i]).remove();

    }
      --col_number;
        }
     });


});
```

But does not work..

Comment: Share the HTML. and I thing it should be `('#column' + i)....`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery delete table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544177/jquery-delete-table-column)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code :

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[id=delete_column]', function () {
    if (col_number > 1) {
    for (var i=0; i<col_number; i++) {
         $('#column' + i).remove();
    };
  }
});
```